# Java EWS - how to get attachment type

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm working on EWS java api, I want to know if an attachment is of type

- ItemAttachment
- FileAttachment

something like this

```
 if (attachment is ItemAttachment) // how to in Java api?
 if (attachment is FileAttachment) // how to in Java api?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instanceof`:

```
if (attachment instanceof ItemAttachment) {
...
}
```